# Is stoichiometric imbalance in polymerization important if the process has an evaporation step?

Tags: chemical-engineering

Polymerization texts stress the importance of stoichiometric balance of the monomers.  For example here:

https://www.e-education.psu.edu/matse202/node/606

I can understand how stoichiometric imbalance leaves some unreacted monomers in the product and this drags down the average molecular weight.  I think this is what the theory is describing.

But, what if the process has subsequent evaporation process to remove light ends?  It seems to me that if this is the case, stoichiometric balance isn't really an issue anymore.  However, maybe there's an another factor I'm not considering.  Appreciate any insight!

Comment: This belongs on the Chemistry Stack.

Comment: Polymers is more of a chemical engineering than a chemistry subject.  For example, the polymer synthesis class on MIT open Courseware is part of the chemical engineering curriculum.  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemical-engineering/10-569-synthesis-of-polymers-fall-2006/

Comment: Engineers touch on many topics, but others do them in greater detail...

Comment: The question is if it is copolymerization ( like ABS ) or polycondensation ( like PET or PC )

Comment: @Poutnik it's specific to step / condensation polymerization where there are two different monomers.  Something like ARA + BRB -> AR2B + AB.  Examples are polyurethane or polyimides.  Stoichiometric imbalance refers to different initial concentrations of the two monomers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in theory, an idealised step-growth AA/BB monomer polycondensation is *exquisitely* sensitive to an imbalance in the ratio of the functional groups A and B present in the reaction mixture, as is described in your link. You're basically exploring the properties of a function close to a vertical asymptote. Since your evaporation step takes place *after* the polymerisation, then it is irrelevant to the polymerisation reaction itself - the excess monomer will already have caused its damage by the time you decide to adjust the weight distribution by some fractionation process (e.g. distilling off monomers/short chains).

The problem is that in your mind, you're unintentionally imagining the weight distribution of a polymer from a balanced polymerisation and then adding a thicker tail at the low weight end (which can be "fixed" by removing the low weight tail altogether). You can't do this - the monomer imbalance will have severely affected the entire weight distribution to start with, and at every step of the reaction. This is how you get the Carothers equation showing how the theoretical degree of polymerisation can vary anywhere from 100 to infinity depending on a reagent imbalance of a mere 1% or less.  You may want to have a look at Paul Flory's 1953 book *Principles of Polymer Chemistry* to really help you absorb the underlying mechanics of a polymerisation reaction. I can definitely recommend it.

Now *in practice* there may not be much difference, though this is dependent on a wild number of real-world parameters (exact reaction kinetics, reagent purities, possible side-reactions, measurement errors, mixing dynamics...) which make it virtually impossible to predict. You're much better off just trying it out on a small scale and seeing what happens. That said, the higher your target degree of polymerisation is, the more fragile the process is. If all you need is an average of a few dozen repeat units per polymer chain, there might be some leeway. If you need thousands or more, then you're in trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm still struggling.  If you have 1 mol/L of A and 1.1 mol/L of B compared to 1 mol/L of each, it seems the excess B would only add to the extent of reaction.  The total amount of chemistry that occurs from an A+B -> product perspective seems like it wouldn't be negatively influenced by the imbalance.  If damage is done by the excess B, what exactly is the nature of the damage?

Comment: Try thinking of a more extreme case, such as having 10 or 100 times more BB monomer than AA monomer. At any point in time, any molecule (monomer, oligomer or polymer) with an A functionality has a large chance of reacting with a BB monomer, simply because there's a lot more BB monomer present than any oligomer/polymer chains containing B functionalities. So almost all reaction events involve adding a single BB monomer to the chain, until all functional groups A are exhausted. Thus, even at high extents of reaction, almost all that happened was the addition of BB monomers to growing chains.

Comment: Now how does this differ from a balanced polymerisation? In this case, as the reaction progresses, the amount of both AA and BB monomers is mostly used up, but there are always an equal number of A and B functionalities still available for reaction. Now, at high extents of reaction, you begin to observe a significant amount of *condensation between chains* (not just a chain + a monomer). This leads to a sudden explosive increase in average molecular weight at the very end - as almost all functional groups are consumed, the chains are forced to join together.

Comment: Thank you Nicolau for the valuable discussion!  You helped me a lot.